# TypeError: JoypadSpace.reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seed', when I run the following code, what should I do to fix this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-api, openai-gym

When I run this code:

```
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
import gym
import gym_super_mario_bros
from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import SIMPLE_MOVEMENT
from gym.wrappers import GrayScaleObservation
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStack,DummyVecEnv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0',apply_api_compatibility=True,render_mode="human")
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)
env = GrayScaleObservation(env,keep_dim=True)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda:env])
env = VecFrameStack(env,4,channels_order='last')
state = env.reset()
```

I get the following error:

[image]

How should I get this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in nes-py (version 8.2.1 as of this answer).

`JoypadSpace` doesn't correctly override the `reset()` method of `Wrapper`.

- `JoypadSpace` `reset()` [was implemented](https://github.com/Kautenja/nes-py/commit/8efb860bb472e99ebb909d8b475a532c11bfff4b) for `gym` 0.10.5 in nes-py 0.8.7 (Jul 2018).
- `Wrapper` `reset()` [was defined](https://github.com/openai/gym/commit/4c460ba6c8959dd8e0a03b13a1ca817da6d4074f) with `**kwargs` in `gym` 0.10.6 (Oct 2018).
  Though at the time `Env` `reset()` did not accept any parameters.
- `Env` `reset()` [started to accept](https://github.com/openai/gym/commit/c36450671090e52243f44fbd20314dd07df6263c) `seed` parameter in `gym` 0.22.0 (Feb 2022).

One-liner workaround:

```py
JoypadSpace.reset = lambda self, **kwargs: self.env.reset(**kwargs)
```

Comment: PR: https://github.com/Kautenja/nes-py/pull/93

Comment: I tried the code proposed here (`JoypadSpace.reset = lambda self, **kwargs: self.env.reset(**kwargs)` , but this time, when I tried executing `env.reset()` I got the error: `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. Can this be fixed in a similar way?

Comment: @GustavoMirapalheta Share the stack trace.

Comment: aaron, I shared the full code used and the stack trace (the error messages) in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77047181/joypadspace-reset-modification-to-solve-unexpected-keyword-argument-seed-l