# JoypadSpace.reset() modification to solve "unexpected keyword argument 'seed'" leads to error: "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Tags: deep-learning, openai-gym, joypad

I'm getting the same error as described here: [TypeError: JoypadSpace.reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seed', when I run the following code, what should I do to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76509663/typeerror-joypadspace-reset-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-seed-when-i) .

In the link above mentioned there's a solution proposed for this problem, which is modifying JoySpace.reset with this code: `JoypadSpace.reset = lambda self, **kwargs: self.env.reset(**kwargs)`.

I tried this solution with the code below:

```
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
JoypadSpace.reset = lambda self, **kwargs: self.env.reset(**kwargs)

from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import SIMPLE_MOVEMENT
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)

from gym.wrappers import GrayScaleObservation
env = GrayScaleObservation(env, keep_dim=True)

from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv    
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])

gameState = env.reset()
obs, _, _, _, _ = env.step(1)
env.close()
```

But this time I got the error:

---

ValueError

```
  Traceback (most recent call last) 

  <ipython-input-3-7521e0795c59> in <cell line: 37>()

  35 

  36 # Size of frame output

  ---> 37 gameState = env.reset()

  38 obs, _, _, _, _ = env.step(1)

  39 env.close()

  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py in reset(self)

  74 def reset(self) -> VecEnvObs:

  75 for env_idx in range(self.num_envs):

  ---> 76 obs, self.reset_infos[env_idx] = self.envs[env_idx].reset(seed=self._seeds[env_idx])

  77 self._save_obs(env_idx, obs)

  78 # Seeds are only used once

  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How can this one be fixed?

Comment: My gym's version is 0.25.2 (I got it using !pip show gym)

Comment: What `env` are you wrapping using `JoypadSpace` in `JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)`?

Comment: `env` was created using: `env = gym_super_mario_bros.make("SuperMarioBros-v3")`

Answer (score 0):

It's an incompatibility between nes-py 8.2.1 (and earlier) and gym 0.26.0 (and later).

`NESEnv` doesn't correctly override the `reset()` method of `Env`.

Workaround:

```py
from nes_py import NESEnv
_reset = NESEnv.reset

def reset(*args, **kwargs):
    obs_info = _reset(*args, **kwargs)
    obs, info = obs_info if type(obs_info) == tuple else (obs_info, {})
    return obs, info

NESEnv.reset = reset
```

Comment: Sorry to say that but now, `gym_super_mario_bros.make("SuperMarioBros-v3")` gives me the error: `TypeError: reset() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`